# Spring Boot: Can I post multiple objects as multiple @RequestParams to a REST service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot I've build a toy REST service with a single resource like so:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/checkout")
public class CheckoutRestController {

    @PostMapping("/book")
    public boolean buyBook(@RequestParam CreditCard creditCard, @RequestParam ShippingAddress shippingAddress) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Both `CreditCard` and `ShippingAddress` are POJOs (plain old Java objects) that I've coded up).

I've tried posting to this endpoint with this payload:

```
{
    "creditCard" : {
        "nameOnCard":"foo",
        "number":12345678,
        "expiryMonth":12,
        "expiryYear":2018,
        "ccv":100
    },
    "shippingAddress" : {
        "steert":"foor",
        "houseNumber":"1a",
        "city":"bar",
        "state":"bazz",
        "country":"buzz",
        "zipCode":"booz"
    },
}
```

But I get an error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-03-13T11:36:52.745+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required CreditCard parameter 'creditCard' is not present",
    "path": "/checkout/book"
}
```

I know a workaround would be to wrap both POJOs in a request wrapper but I'd rather not unless I really have to.

Is it possible to post two @RequestParam annotated objects? If so, what would the JSON look like?

Comment: Create another class and create objects ,gettter ,setter for CreditCard,ShippingAddress then use @requestBody object of new class

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@RequestParam` parameters are *query* parameters, not body parameters.

This means that your method:

```
@PostMapping("/book")
public boolean buyBook(@RequestParam CreditCard creditCard, @RequestParam 
    ShippingAddress shippingAddress) {

        return true;
}
```

Expects the following request:

```
POST /checkout/book?creditCard=<...>&shippingAddress=<...>
```

However, Spring doesn't know how to convert a `String` query parameter to `CreditCard` or to `ShippingAddress`.

You might solve this by implementing a `Converter`, as follows:

```
public class StringToCreditCardConverter implements Converter<String, CreditCard> {

    @Override
    public CreditCard convert(String source) {
         <...>
    }
}
```

However, I do not recommend this as it is not the standard for request bodies and would cause quite a lot of confusion and maintainability issues.

Instead, the recommended way is as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/book")
public boolean buyBook(@RequestBody BookCreationRequest bookCreationRequest) {
        CreditCard creditCard = bookCreationRequest.getCreditCard();
        ShippingAddress shippingAddress = bookCreationRequest.getShippingAddress();
        ...
}
```

With the `bookCreationRequest` containing the `CreditCard` and `ShippingAddress` fields (note: you could use e.g. [`lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/) to reduce the boilerplate code):

```
public class BookCreationRequest {
    private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;
    private CreditCredit creditCard;

    public ShippingAddress  getShippingAddress() {...}
    public CreditCard       getCreditCard() {...}

    public BookCreationRequest(ShippingAddress shippingAddress, CreditCard creditCard) {
        this.creditCard = creditCard;
        this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
}
```

Which would then expect a request JSON as follows:

```
POST /checkout/book
Payload:
{
    "creditCard": {
        ... 
    },
    "shippingAddress": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that there can only be a single `@RequestBody` parameter in a request.

Comment: Very well articulated

Comment: If I want to pass multiple objects via POST? Only one requestbody is allowed... I ideally don't want to create new class composed of those objects... could you please suggest what one can do?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - create a wrapper Request object.
It's not a workaround - it's actually the recommended approach.

You see in your json you have:

```
{ //wrapper
 {}, //first complex data object / mapped to pojo
 {} //second complex data object / mapped to pojo
}
```

1) You can easily apply validation to your Request object with `@Valid` and hence validate both POJOs.

2) You don't have to worry about the order in the payload.

3) You're using `@RequestParam` incorrectly. `@RequestBody` is what maps the whole POST payload. You have to remove the `@RequestParam` annotation and use `@RequestBody` instead.

Comment: OK this should solve my problem then. I'm using enc-multipart as type though (to support upload of a file). The upload works if I JUST handle the file. But I also have a book object thats passed to the view and fields are taken from my form. So I should be able to create a wrapper for the Book and the Multipart File?

Comment: Do I need to create a java class composed of the 2 POJOs to receive this?

Comment: @AB yes, that's correct